# Invariance by isometries of Fisher inner product/Bombieri norm

Tags: derivatives, polynomials, reference-request

Let $p$ and $q$ be two homogeneous polynomials in $n$ variables. Then the *Fisher inner product* is defined by
$$\langle p,q\rangle\colon = (\partial(p)\overline{q})(0),$$
where $\partial(p)\colon = p(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1},\ldots,\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2})$. For example, for $p=q=x_1^2x_2$ we have $\langle p,q\rangle=(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_1^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}x_1^2x_2)(0)=2$. In general, if $p$ and $q$ are homogeneous of different degree, $\langle p,q\rangle=0$, as well as $\langle x^\alpha,x^\beta\rangle=0$ for $\alpha\neq\beta\in\Bbb N^n$.

If $A\in M_n(\Bbb R)$ is a matrix, it acts on homogeneous polynomials by $$(A.p)(x)\colon = p(A^{-1}x).$$
If $A\in\mathrm{O}(n)$ is orthogonal it seems to be true that $\langle Ap,Aq\rangle=\langle p,q\rangle$, see e.g. the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombieri_norm) where some integral representation is claimed; however I could not find a reference to that claim and think that there should be a direct proof of this fact. Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f_i,\ g_i\in\Bbb R^n$ for each $i\in\{1,\ldots,m\}$ for some $m\in\Bbb N$ and $f\colon = \prod_{j=1}^m\langle x,f_i\rangle_2,\ g\colon = \prod_{j=1}^m\langle x,g_j\rangle_2$ one has
$$\langle f,g\rangle=\sum_{\sigma\in S_m}\prod_{j=1}^m\langle f_i,g_{\sigma(i)}\rangle_2,$$
which can be proven by expanding $f$ and $g$ into sums of monomials and using $\langle x^\alpha,x^\beta\rangle=0$ for $\alpha\neq\beta$ and $\langle x^\alpha,x^\alpha\rangle=\alpha !$.
Using this characterization the invariance by isometries follows readily for polynomials of the above form. However, each monomial of degree $m$ is of this form and therefore the invariance is true for all homogeneous polynomials.